# Match expression on child attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML file like this:

```
 <comp ref="C2">
    <value>100uF</value>
    <footprint>Capacitors_SMD:c_elec_6.3x7.7</footprint>
    <datasheet>EEEFK1V101XP</datasheet>
    <fields>
      <field name="Manufacturer">Panasonic</field>
      <field name="Voltage">35V</field>
      <field name="Symbol">EEEFK1V101XP</field>
    </fields>
    <libsource lib="device" part="CP"/>
    <sheetpath names="/" tstamps="/"/>
    <tstamp>57B38AFC</tstamp>
</comp>

<comp ref="C1">
  <value>100uF</value>
  <footprint>Capacitors_SMD:c_elec_6.3x7.7</footprint>
  <fields>
    <field name="Voltage">25V</field>
    <field name="Symbol">2345</field>
  </fields>
  <libsource lib="device" part="CP"/>
  <sheetpath names="/" tstamps="/"/>
  <tstamp>57B492EF</tstamp>
</comp>
```

I want to display this components separately because they are not similar.
When I use `datasheet` node it works.

```
<xsl:key name="partTypeByValueAndFootprint" match="comp" use="concat(datasheet, '-', footprint, '-', value)" />

<xsl:for-each select="comp[count(. | key('partTypeByValueAndFootprint', concat(datasheet, '-', footprint, '-', value))[1]) = 1]">
<xsl:sort select="@ref" />
```

But I don't know why when I use `fields/field/@name="Symbol"` it doesn't work.

```
<xsl:key name="partTypeByValueAndFootprint" match="comp" use="concat(fields/field/@name='Symbol', '-', footprint, '-', value)" />

    <xsl:for-each select="comp[count(. | key('partTypeByValueAndFootprint', concat(fields/field/@name='Symbol', '-', footprint, '-', value))[1]) = 1]">
    <xsl:sort select="@ref" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `fields/field/@name='Symbol'` you want `fields/field[@name='Symbol']`. The square brackets represent a condition to be applied to the selected nodes.

For example....

```
<xsl:key name="partTypeByValueAndFootprint" 
         match="comp" 
         use="concat(fields/field[@name='Symbol'], '-', footprint, '-', value)" />
```